# What is the study examining biological sex differences in determination where babies pulled on a string to generate a response?

Tags: behaviorism, sex-differences

I'm looking for the study that describes this experiment. I saw it demonstrated in a documentary, but I can't remember the name of it.

In the experiment, biological males and females were put in a seat facing a screen with a string attached to their arm, and when they pulled the string, the picture changed. The researchers then stopped the picture from changing when the string was pulled to observe behaviour differences between the two groups.